# prove that $(n-1)(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\hat{\sigma^2_{-i}}-\hat{\sigma^2})=-\frac{S^2}{n}$ in i.i.d sample(the factor n-1 in the jackknife bias)

Tags: statistical-inference, sampling-theory

let $x=(x_1,\cdots,x_n) $ are *n* independent samples from unknown distribution. The Jackknife Samples are selected by taking the original data vector and
deleting one observation from the set. Thus, there are n unique Jackknife samples, and the *i*th Jackknife sample vector is defined as:

$$x_{-i}=(x_1,\cdots,x_{i-1},x_{i+1},\cdots,x_n) $$

The *i*th Jackknife Replicate is defined as the value of the estimator $\hat{\theta}= s(x)$ evaluated at the *i*th
Jackknife sample.
$$\hat{\theta}_{-i}= s(x_{-i})$$
The Jackknife Standard Error is defined as
$$\hat{se}=\sqrt{\frac{n-1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} (\hat{\theta}_{-i}-\hat{\theta}_{.})^2}$$
where
$$\hat{\theta}_{.}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\hat{\theta}_{-i}$$
The Jackknife Bias is defined as
$$\hat{bias}_{jack}=(n-1)(\hat{\theta}_{.}- \hat{\theta})$$
where $\hat{\theta}=s(x)$ is the estimator taking the entire sample as argument.

**The question is where come from the factor "n-1"? 
or prove**

$$(n-1)\left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\hat{\sigma^2_{-i}}-\hat{\sigma^2}\right)=-\frac{S^2}{n}$$ where

$$\hat{\sigma^2}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\bar{x})^2$$
$$\hat{\sigma_{-i}^2}=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{j=1\neq i}^{n}(x_j-\bar{x}_{-i})^2$$
$$S^2=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\bar{x})^2$$

I read this http://people.bu.edu/aimcinto/jackknife.pdf and it say:

I consider as an estimator the uncorrected variance of the sample:
$$s(x)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\bar{x})^2$$
If I take as my estimator $\hat{\theta}=s(x)$ the (biased) sample variance, I have that its bias, that is, $E[\hat{\theta}-\theta]$, is
equal to $-\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$. If I use the Jackknife bias as an estimate for the bias of my estimator, and I have
that my estimator $\hat{\theta})$ is equal to the uncorrected sample variance, then the Jackknife bias formula
reduces to $-\frac{S^2}{n}$, where $S^2$ is now the regular, corrected, unbiased estimator of sample variance.
Thus, the bias here is constructed from a heuristic notion to emulate the bias of the uncorrected
sample variance.

**My try**

$$(n-1)(\hat{\sigma^2_{.}}-\hat{\sigma^2})=(n-1)\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \hat{\sigma^2_{-i}} - \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\bar{x})^2 \right)$$

$$=\frac{n-1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left( \hat{\sigma^2_{-i}}- (x_i-\bar{x})^2\right)$$

$$=\frac{n-1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(  \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{j=1,j\neq i}(x_j-\bar{x}_{-i})^2- (x_i-\bar{x})^2\right)$$

$$=\frac{n-1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{j=1}^{n} (x_j-\bar{x}_{-i})^2-\frac{1}{n-1}(x_i-\bar{x}_{-i})^2- (x_i-\bar{x})^2\right)$$
since 
$$\bar{x}_{-i}=\frac{n \bar{x}-x_i}{n-1}$$

$$=\frac{n-1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left( \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{j=1}^n ( x_j-\frac{n \bar{x}-x_i}{n-1})^2-\frac{1}{n-1}(x_i-\frac{n \bar{x}-x_i}{n-1})^2- (x_i-\bar{x})^2\right)$$

$$=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^n ( x_j-\frac{n \bar{x}-x_i}{n-1})^2-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\frac{n \bar{x}-x_i}{n-1})^2-\frac{n-1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i-\bar{x})^2$$

$$=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^n ( x_j-\frac{n \bar{x}-x_i}{n-1})^2-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\frac{nx_i-n \bar{x}}{n-1})^2-\frac{n-1}{n}(n-1)S^2$$

$$=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^n ( x_j-\frac{n \bar{x}-x_i}{n-1})^2-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{n^2}{(n-1)^2}(x_i- \bar{x})^2-\frac{n-1}{n}(n-1)S^2$$

$$=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^n ( x_j-\frac{n \bar{x}-x_i}{n-1})^2-\frac{n}{(n-1)^2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i- \bar{x})^2-\frac{n-1}{n}(n-1)S^2$$

$$=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^n ( x_j-\frac{n \bar{x}-x_i}{n-1})^2-\frac{n}{(n-1)^2}(n-1)S^2-\frac{n-1}{n}(n-1)S^2$$

$$=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^n ( x_j-\frac{n \bar{x}-x_i}{n-1})^2-\frac{n}{(n-1)}S^2-\frac{n-1}{n}(n-1)S^2$$

$$=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^n ( x_j-\frac{n \bar{x}-x_i}{n-1})^2-S^2 \left(\frac{n}{n-1}+\frac{(n-1)^2}{n}\right)$$

$$=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^n ( x_j-\frac{n \bar{x}-x_i}{n-1})^2-S^2 \left(\frac{n^2+(n-1)^3}{n(n-1)}\right)$$

$$=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^n ( x_j-\frac{n \bar{x}-x_i}{n-1})^2-S^2 \left(\frac{n^2+n^3-3n^2+3n-1}{n(n-1)}\right)$$

$$=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^n ( x_j-\frac{n \bar{x}-x_i}{n-1})^2-S^2 \left(\frac{n^3-2n^2+3n-1}{n(n-1)}\right)$$

if I calculate
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^n ( x_j-\frac{n \bar{x}-x_i}{n-1})^2$$
it is done!
$$=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^n (\frac{(n-1)(x_j -\bar{x})+(x_i-\bar{x})}{n-1})^2$$

$$=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^n ((x_j -\bar{x})+\frac{(x_i-\bar{x})}{n-1})^2$$

$$=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^n ((x_j -\bar{x})^2+\frac{(x_i-\bar{x})^2}{(n-1)^2})$$

$$=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} n (x_j -\bar{x})^2+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n} n\frac{(x_i-\bar{x})^2}{(n-1)^2}+0$$

$$=(n-1)S^2+\frac{S^2}{n-1}=S^2\frac{(n-1)^2+1}{n-1}=S^2\frac{n^2-2n+2}{n-1}$$

so

$$(n-1)(\hat{\sigma^2_{.}}-\hat{\sigma^2})=S^2\frac{n^2-2n+2}{n-1}-S^2\frac{n^3-2n^2+3n-1}{n(n-1)}$$

$$(n-1)(\hat{\sigma^2_{.}}-\hat{\sigma^2})=S^2\left(\frac{n^3-2n^2+2n-n^3+2n^2-3n+1}{n(n-1)}\right)$$

$$(n-1)(\hat{\sigma^2_{.}}-\hat{\sigma^2})=S^2\left(\frac{-n+1}{n(n-1)}\right)=-\frac{S^2}{n}$$

It is done. is these calculations correct?(it seems)